# manually set check box selected in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, checkbox

I have a CheckBox in as3 that i need to set as checked with code. Do I dispatch an event?  If so, how do I create an event, and give it a target (target is read only).  Or is there another way to do it?  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_checkbox.selected = true;
```

And of course:

```
my_checkbox.selected = false;
```

To handle the box being checked/unchecked:

```
my_checkbox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _selected);
function _selected(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var bool:Boolean = e.target.selected;

    if(bool)
    {
        trace("was checked");
        // more code
    }
    else
    {
        trace("was unchecked");
        // more code
    }
}
```